# add a column of checkboxes to a grid that will update a field in a database

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, vb.net, visual-studio

I have a GridView holding my order table that aappears on my docor page (these are inserted values from an insert statement) - this is the select statement:

```
Create View docgridview 
As 

Select A.OrderID
  ,A.DoctorId,B.Forename,B.Surname ,A.MedicineId,C.Name      as      MedicineName,D.pharmname,A.Dateordered, Approved
From  order_pres  A
Left  Join Patient   B on (A.PatientId  = B.PatientId)
Left  Join Medicine  C on (A.MedicineId = C.MedicineId)
Left  Join pharmacy  D on (A.PharmacyId   = D.PharmacyId)
Left  Join Doctor    E on (A.DoctorId  = E.DoctorId)
```

Docgridview is then used to bind the statement to the gridview:

```
 If Not IsPostBack Then
        Dim conn As New System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection("Data Source=(LocalDB)\v11.0;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\surgerydb.mdf;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30")
        Dim cmd3string As String = " Select * From docgridview  WHERE DoctorId = " & Session("DoctorId")
        Dim dt As New System.Data.DataTable()
        Dim da As New System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter(cmd3string, conn)
        conn.Open()
        da.Fill(dt)
        conn.Close()

        GridViewdoc.DataSource = dt
        GridViewdoc.DataBind()
    End If
```

How do I add a column of check boxes to a GridView that would update the column approved from the order_pres  'approved' if checked and 'disapproved' if not checked on the button . click

the grid view:

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridViewdoc" runat="server"  >

</asp:GridView>


<asp:Button ID="btnapprove" runat="server" Text="Button" />
```

The table that will update:

[image]

Comment: Before you do anything else you should read about, understand and start using parameterized queries. The session is actually pretty safe but the pattern of query there suggest sql injection is highly likely in other spots in your system. As for the actual question I am a little confused. You state you want a checkbox column but then talk about clicking the button? I would think that just the checkbox is enough. Then setup an event handler for the onclick event.

Comment: There will be a number of orders in the grid you see so the button. Click confirms this

Comment: Huh? What do you mean by see the button? You don't need a button, you just need a checkbox.

Comment: Sean, there will be more than one order on the grid - what I need the check box to do once checked is update the appoved colum to the value approved - if there is no check then it will update to not approved on the button. click

Comment: I would hope there is more than 1 order. This is why I said you need to have a checkbox in the grid. And add an event handler to the checkbox to update the data for the current row. When the state of the checked property changes it will update the row.

Comment: this is what I dont know what to do, do you have an example?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/117249/discussion-between-sean-lange-and-laurajs).

Answer (score 0):

You would need to manually define the columns in the gridview:

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridViewdoc" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
      <Columns>
           <asp:BoundField DataField="OrderID"></asp:BoundField>
           <asp:BoundField DataField="DoctorId"></asp:BoundField>
           <asp:BoundField DataField="Forename"></asp:BoundField>
           <asp:BoundField DataField="Surname"></asp:BoundField>
           <asp:BoundField DataField="MedicineId"></asp:BoundField>
           <asp:BoundField DataField="MedicineName"></asp:BoundField>
           <asp:BoundField DataField="pharmname"></asp:BoundField>
           <asp:BoundField DataField="Dateordered"></asp:BoundField>
           <asp:BoundField DataField="Approved"></asp:BoundField>
           <asp:TemplateField>
               <ItemTemplate>
                   <asp:CheckBox Text="Approve" ID="ApproveBox" runat="server" />
               </ItemTemplate>
           </asp:TemplateField>
      </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

That last column is the checkbox column. Add a handler for GridViewdoc.RowDataBound to set the boxes to checked (since it looks like you are defaulting them all to Approved)

```
Protected Sub GridViewdoc_RowDataBound(sender As Object, e As System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridViewRowEventArgs) Handles GridViewdoc.RowDataBound
    If e.Row.RowType = DataControlRowType.DataRow Then
        CType(e.Row.FindControl("ApproveBox"), Checkbox).Checked = True
    End If
End Sub
```

And then process which boxes are checked and unchecked in your button click event handler. As for changing the data, you will need to use a session or cache variable to store the data table so you can modify its data and re-bind the gridview with the changed data.

```
Protected Sub btnapprove_Click(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnapprove.Click
    Dim dt As Data.DataTable = Session("YourDataTableVariable") 
    For Each row As GridViewRow In GridViewdoc.Rows
        Dim cb As CheckBox = row.FindControl("ApproveBox")
        If cb.checked Then
            dt.Rows(row.RowIndex).Item(8) = "Approved"
        Else
            dt.Rows(row.RowIndex).Item(8) = "Disapproved"
        End If
    Next
    GridViewdoc.DataSource = dt
    GridViewdoc.DataBind()
End Sub
```

Comment: thank you very much for taking time to answer this, I am just about to test this - in regards to the approved set to bit , should I change this if this is the column going to be updated to these values? thank you :)

Comment: You could either change the bit to a string or continue using the bit and change the code I provided to set it to the correct value.

Comment: Hi @wenadin - is there any reason the checked= true wouldn't work? Thank u:)

Comment: I edited that portion of my answer to fix the issue.

Comment: hi @wenadin - I got this error with the .checked An exception of type 'System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException' occurred in System.Web.dll but was not handled in user code

Additional information: Specified argument was out of the range of valid values.

Comment: could it be because I have changed my check box to '<ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:CheckBox ID="Approvebox" AutoPostBack="true"  runat="server" CommandName="UpdateApproved" CommandArgument='<%# Eval("Approved")%>'/>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>'

Comment: visual studio has an issue with using the ID for check box when I added the check box from your code for some reason

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/117457/discussion-between-laurajs-and-wenadin).

Comment: hi @wenadin  can you come back to the discussion please